# Query to read a query in a file

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have huge create table queries (100's  of Gb) which I'd like to ship throught ODBC to my db (Postgre in that case). The problem is that these queries are built from an external program, so I would like to avoid loading each query in memory to ship it by ODBC to the db. I would much prefer to indicate to the db in a (small) query to go execute that huge query directly.

That could be easy with psql, but I'd like to do it throught odbc. Is it possible ?

Comment: If you can do it with psql why is it you want to do it with odbc, any real reason?

Comment: Well, I considered that the connection to the database with ODBC was managed not by my code (e.g. I didn't have to store a password, or other parameters) and that it would be more consistent with the rest of my code instead of jumping from odbc to the shell. But, as you ask the question, it makes me think that maybe I could use plsql with DO command in sql. I'm going to take a look at it. It would provide the advantages of both !

Comment: I finally did it with psql as it seems impossible to do using ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean bulk data load, PostgreSQL has COPY command - it can read the data file on the server directly but it can not process regular SQL queries - it can load data from file in the CSV or similiar format (which you can customize as a COPY parameters).

If you're loading table from scratch nice optimizations are having plain table (without PK, FK, constraints, indexes), and executing the COPY in the transaction together with TRUNCATE table like:

BEGIN;
TRUNCATE ....;
COPY ...;
COMMIT;

Comment: The problem is that the files are containing the SQL query to create the tables.

Comment: Maybe you should try writing plsql function which will read the file with pg_read_file() and then EXECUTE 'sql'; See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-admin.html & http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-statements.html